# highcharts grid lines are dissappearing on zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, grouping, categories

I am using highcharts to display charts in my project. Everything is great but when I use zoom buttons the grid lines are dissapearing.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this?

Below is my code. I did not change much from the examples provided in highcharts.com.

I get the chart with grid lines first without any problem. Only when I use zoom buttons grid lines dissapear. This is not happening with highcharts examples.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: <id of my div>
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [ 
            {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }
            ],
            selected:3,
          inputPosition:{
                    x:25,
                    y:25,
                    align:"left"
             },
            align:"left"
        },
        title: {
            margin:40,
            text: title,
            style:{
                color:"#000",
                fontFamily: "AvenirNextLTW01-MediumC 721311 !important",
                fontWeight:"bold",
                fontSize:"12px"
            }
        },
        scrollbar : {
            enabled : false
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: ytitle
            },
            lineWidth: 2,
        }],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        loading:{
            style: {
                position: 'absolute',
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                opacity: 0.5,
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        },
        tooltip: 
            {
               valueDecimals: 2,
               style:{
                 fontSize:'9px'
               }
            },
        series: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            color: '#4572A7',
            name: title,
            data: <data array>
        }]
    });
```

Edit: I have used the following plug in my website for grouping categories in x-axis. The above problem occurs wherever I used this plugin. Can anybody suggest what I can change to get rid of this problem? Or can anyone suggest an other plugin which gives this functionality?

http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/

I have used this plugin code in following jsfiddle and could reproduce the issue.
Click on zoom(1y,6m) buttons in this fiddle and observe that grid lines are disappearing

http://jsfiddle.net/92NDX/

Comment: Can't see any issue: http://jsfiddle.net/gfNYk/6/

Comment: Could you reproduce your example in jsfiddle.net ? because we have no data in your code

Comment: Yes. I myself can't reproduce this in jsfiddle. I will post the link once the site is completed

Comment: please look at the jsfiddle I have posted

Comment: Grouped categories works only with highcharts and categories, not with highstock / datetime axis.

Comment: yeah...What if I use two kind of charts in the same page?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Please look in the fiddle I posted.

Comment: It is only highstock, but categories insisde highstock cannot be used, only in highcharts

Comment: Ok. Is there any other plugin you know that can do this and not disturb highstock charts?

Comment: Unforutantley not, but we fixed a few bugs in this plugin, liek disappearing gridlines, so please test with the newest version, your specific example.